# How can I create a random function that avoids a user writing Strings

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to create a function that lets a user enters 2 numbers (`from` and `to`)
but I don't want them to make `from` larger than `to` and don't want them to enter a String (I tried if (from is String) but it doesn't work)

```
fun rand() {

    println("Enter First number: ")
    var first = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter second number")
    val second = readLine()!!.toInt()
    if(second - first < 0) {
        do {
            println("You have to make sure that your first number is larger than the second")
            println("Enter your First number: ")
            val first = readLine()!!.toInt()
            print("Please enter a number smaller than the first number")
            val second: Int = readLine()!!.toInt()
        } while(first - second < 0)

    }
    val random = Random().nextInt(second - first) + first
    println("Your number is $random")
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't want them to enter a String" - the user will have to enter something after all and if the keyboard is used it will be a string in some form or another. Do you mean to only allow numbers to be entered?

Comment: Yes, I don't want them to enter something like sfafsdf and if they do I want the program to repeat the process

Comment: In that case you could try to parse the input as a number (not sure whether `toInt()` does that) and if that fails you repeat much like you do with `first > second` .

Comment: It wont work, I wonder if theres a class that allows the user to enter only numbers

Comment: Well I can't tell you for Kotlin but in Java you'd either use `Scanner.nextInt()` but that might wait until a number is entered or you'd read the string and try to parse it (e.g. `Integer.parseInt(input)`) and catch the exception. Afaik there's no way to restrict input on the command line.

Comment: It is possible to use regex if you make some sort of TextField but not sure if in this case that is possible other than checking